# Bootstrap 3 secondary menu using nav-pills below navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and would like to know if it's possible to add a secondary menu using nav-pills, but I want it to behave like a secondary navbar.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hquzXy252M

My menu code html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li ng-class="{active: routeBeginsWith('/admin/users')}"><a href="#/admin/users"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User Management</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{active: routeBeginsWith('/admin/sites')}"><a href="#/admin/sites"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Site Management</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{active: routeBeginsWith('/admin/email')}"><a href="#/admin/email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the nav-pills in a container, and `position:fixed` that container right below the primary nav. <s>However, my simple approach here falls apart on mobile. You'll need another solution (or more complex css) if you want it to work on mobile too.</s>

```
.nav-2{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  background:#eee;
}
```

**Example: http://www.bootply.com/I4e9jzllNT#**

**EDIT: Fixed for mobile**

As long as you use a responsive primary nav, and correct margins and padding on your pill container, it works ok on mobile too: **http://www.bootply.com/ozq7nO6H2O**

```
.nav-2{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  background:#eee;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

(confirmed addition of z-index:2 fixed final problem; after some discussion in chat)

Comment: I took your code and it doesn't work for me. The content in container-2 still scrolls over top of the secondary menu. I literally pasted your CSS in my code, so I'm not sure why. I am using the row class in my version code.

Comment: Hmm. Must be other styling affecting it but no way to know without seeing your css. Can you paste all you html and css into a bootply (or here as well)?

Comment: I'm not sure if the top bar has something to do with it. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXeip0Ka22s) that show my changes as you suggest and the behaviour.

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but might need to go nuclear with z-index. First try adding z-index:2; to the .nav-2 css. And then try z-index:10000.

Comment: I think that's the wrong bootply - exactly same as mine and works fine:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55079/discussion-between-andyczerwonka-and-shawn-taylor).